# How to change an absolute path to a relative path in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, path, relative-path

My absolute path works for me :

```
const string fileName = 
@"C:\Udvikling\MapEditor\MapEditorProject\Data\Track1.xml";
```

But I want a relative path.
I try'ed :

```
const string fileName = @"~\Data\Track1.xml";
```

I get this Error:

"Could not find a part of the path 
     C:\Udvikling\RollerApp\RollerGame\MapEditorProject\bin\Debug\~\Data\Track1.xml'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add `~` character and use Path.Combine method to combine 2 paths.

More or less like this:

```
const string fileName = @"\Data\Track1.xml";

string combinedPath =  Path.Combine(@"C:\Udvikling\RollerApp\RollerGame\MapEditorProject\bin\Debug", 
         fileName);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes that's right. thanks. But also, isn't there a Application.SomethingStatic I should use for the "left" part of the track?

Comment: @radbyx: you probabbly referencing to [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)

Comment: Yes! It can replace my first part. But It's not all there though. but maybe it's just me. Maybe i'm doing something other thing wrong too. The XML file should be somewhere in the bin directory instead. Because the first part of the path would never be right on another computer?

Comment: I just wan't my buddy to get the XML file too, when he Update with SVN.. So where or how should I place that shared xml file :S

Comment: @radbyx: correct, but you're actually asking about **relative** path. Who cares about exact path on another computer ? What you know is the **relative** layout of your program files, and this you can achieve by computing the path in a this way.

Comment: Like this right?

                const string relativePath = @"\Data\Track1.xml";
                string combinedPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, relativePath);

Comment: are you looking for `Application.UserAppDataPath` for your xml data, the below [MSDN UserAppDataPath] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath.aspx) could help you?

Comment: I think I got it now, with use of "copy to output" for my .XML file

Comment: Final solution: Set XML file to "Copy file to output" and 
const string relativePath = "data\\Track1.xml";
                string combinedPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, relativePath); Big thanks Tigran! :)

Comment: Ups ofcourse use                 const string relativePath = @"data\Track1.xml";
 also